# Linq Grouping and averages

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects one is a car object and the other object I use to log how many car objects are on shift and record what properties these cars have.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool OnShift { get; set; }
    public bool HasExtraBaggageSpace { get; set; }


}

public class Log
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public bool HasExtraBaggageSpace { get; set; }

}
```

Every five minutes the app selects all the cars on shift and writes the information to a log object   and inserts them into a List Logs.

After three weeks of logging I would now like to return a number which reflects the average of the last three weeks . Example:
How many cars with HasExtraBaggageSpace can I expect on a thursday at 14:00.

public class myApp
   {

```
  public class AverageReturnArgs
     {
       public int Hour { get; set; }
       public int Minute { get; set; }
       public int Count { get; set; }

     }



    public AverageReturnArgs GetAverage(List<Log> logs, DateTime TimeReq)
    {
        int hour = TimeReq.Hour;
        int min = TimeReq.Minute;
        var average = logs.GroupBy(grpByHourMin => new
        {
            hour = grpByHourMin.TimeStamp.Hour,
            min = grpByHourMin.TimeStamp.Minute
        }).Select(av => new AverageReturnArgs()
        {
            Hour = av.Key.hour,
            Minute = av.Key.min,
            Count = av.Average(x => x.HasExtraBaggageSpace)
        });
    }
}
```

This is producing a compiler error.
   Count = av.Average(x => x.HasExtraBaggageSpace)

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you calculate the average of boolean values ?
I think the Count aggregate should be what you are looking for:

```
Count = av.Count(x => x.HasExtraBaggageSpace)
```

**EDIT** If you mean to calculate the percentage of cars having *ExtraBaggageSpace* you may try something like this :

```
Count = av.Average(x => x.HasExtraBaggageSpace ? 1 : 0)
```

With use of the ternary operator this expression convert your boolean value to an integer and calculate the average (that will be a Double).

**EDIT 2**

Here is what your line should look like.
Count should be made of type Double.

```
Count = av.Average(x => av.Count(y=>y.HasExtraBaggageSpace))
```

**EDIT 3**

Ok the logic was all wrong :

```
public AverageReturnArgs GetAverage(List<Log> logs, DateTime TimeReq)
{
    int hour = TimeReq.Hour;
    int min = TimeReq.Minute;
    var average = logs
    .Where(log => log.TimeStamp.Hour == hour && log.TimeStamp.Minute == min)
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.TimeStamp)
    .Select(av => new AverageReturnArgs()
    {
        Hour = hour,
        Minute = min,
        Count = av.Average(x => av.Count(y=>y.HasExtraBaggageSpace))
    });
}
```

Comment: What I mean is that at 14:00 on every thursday for past three weeks there is n logs. Some of these will have HasExtraBaggageSpace and some wont. If week1 =3 week2 = 2  week3 = 1 average is 2.

Comment: Well I could but it's as simple as counting a boolean property at three different times and averaging them. That pretty much it. Just can't get the linq syntax.Sorry if original question vague.

Comment: Can you try my EDIT 2 ? It calculates first for each group the count of *Logs* having *ExtraBaggageSpace* and then calculate the Average across all groups.

Comment: EDIT 2 returns the count and not the average. If wk1 = 1 wk2 =1 wk3 =1 it should return average = 1 but it return 3

Comment: Ok, the logic was wrong. In the EDIT 3, I filter the logs for the ones matching the hour and minute (that's the only ones intersting in your case). From then I group the records by date and calculate the count for each date having extra baggage space. I finally calculate the average accross all groups.

Comment: If you really want by week, you need to add a criteria on DayOfWeek, because in your original code you are only filtering on hour and minute so there is a group per day instead of a group per week.